# Issue with Paginiation

Tags: python, django, pagination

I am quite new to python/django and I am following CoreyMSchafer's youtube tutorials.

However, when trying to get pagination to work it displays the elif command on the webpage itself and doesn't render it server side.[elif code being displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDHCJ.png)

home.html

```
{% if is_paginated %} {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
<a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page=1">First</a>
<a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a> {% endif %} {% for num in page_obj.paginator.page_range %} {% if page_obj.number == num %}
<a class="btn btn-info mb-4" href="?page={{ num }}">{{ num }}</a> 
{% elif num > page_obj.number|add:'-3' and num < page_obj.number|add: '3' %} <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ num }}">{{ num }}</a>
    {% endif %} {% endfor %} {% if page_obj.has_next %}
    <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">Last</a> {% endif %} {% endif %} {% endblock content %}
```

Comment: It is `page_obj.number|add:'3`, not `page_obj.number|add: '3`.

Comment: thank you, it appeared i had an extension on that auto-formatted that particular spacing.